# Error: Call to undefined function on $.load()

Tags: php, jquery

In a page the external files with function used (functions.php) are loaded into the header. On $(document).ready() is executed a function that after a period of time reloads the contents of a div using $.load():

> $('#area').load('area.php');

In area.php a php function of a library included in the header is used, but when the "reload" is executed the responce is:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function...

I have tried :

- other alternative but similar solutions
- include in area.php the library with the function used (include_once('functions.php');

I can't solve the problem.

Could you tell me why that error is returned to me? as if the file with the functions used had not been loaded which is instead included in the header?

Comment: That is a javascript (jQuery) function call. Nothing to do with PHP code. Did you include the jQuery library in the page code

Comment: Can you change `include` to `require`? That should throw a fatal error if the file fails to be included. Perhaps the path for the include is failing

Comment: When the page is first loaded, everything is done correctly, even _area.php_. I add `require ('includes/required.php') ` in _area.php_, the response is: `Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'includes/required.php' (include_path='.:') in...`. (includes/required.php contains all files used on the page )

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you are trying to refresh part of a html page. I am assuming that because in your question you have that part (**after a period of time reloads the contents of a div**).
I guess you need to do something like the following.

For example, your jQuery or JavaScript will look something like

```
// Define AJAX function.
ajaxReloadDiv = function () { 
   // The body of your AJAX function.
   // Here you can call php method etc.
}

// Call the function first time.
ajaxReloadDiv();

// Then call it every 20 second.
setInterval(ajaxReloadDiv, 20000);
```

Or you can do something like the following

```
// Set interval 10 second.
setInterval("reloadDiv();", 10000);

function reloadDiv() {
  $('#my-div').load('area.php #container');
}
```

When this method executes, it retrieves the content of **area.php**, but then jQuery parses the returned document to find the element with an ID of **container**. This element, along with its contents, is inserted into the element with an ID of result, and the rest of the retrieved document is discarded.

Check that as well https://api.jquery.com/load/

Hope that will helps you in same way.